# MySQL Workbench panel

Tags: mysql-workbench

I Can't access the Navigation panel in MySQL Workbench. Currently have this: [image]
What can I do?

Comment: Please add more information. Version of the used software and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Click on **view->pannel->show sidebar**

***Answer Updated:***
Take your mouse cursor at the **object info** 
or at **session** in the left corner of workbench then drag this section to the down. Management pannel will be visible there. 
Hope this would help you.

Comment: This is correct. There is a splitter between the schema tree and the object info panels. And it seems that splitter has been fully moved up (there's a slightly thicker line above the "Object Info" and "Session" tabs. Place your mouse on that line and drag it down.